# getting the previous month value

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to get previous month data, for that I am using lag function but not getting the desired results.

```
ut  cntr         src    Item    section Year    Period  css    fct       ytd_1     ytd_1*fct    aproach1    aproach2
  49    52      179     f         84    2019    1      63   0.616580311 5578.092    3439.341699     0             0
  e4    52      179     f         84    2019    1      31   0.248704663 5578.092    1387.297492     0             0
  49    52      179     f         84    2019    1      31   0.248704663 5578.092    1387.297492     0             0
  a5    52      179     f         84    2019    1      31   0.248704663 5578.092    1387.297492     0             0
  49    52      179     f         84    2019    2      63   0.080405405 18506.982   1488.061391    3439.341    5578.092
  49    52      179     f         84    2019    2      31   0.072297297 18506.982   1338.00478     1387.29     5578.092
  e4    52      187     f         84    2019    2      31   0.072297297 18506.982   1338.00478     1387.29     5578.092
  e4    52      179     f         84    2019    2      31   0.072297297 18506.982   1338.00478     1387.29     5578.092
```

code:

```
w_lag = Window.partitionBy(['Item','section','section','css','Year']).orderBy(spark_func.asc('Period'))
df_lag = df_unit.withColumn('approach', spark_func.lead(df_unit['ytd_1']).over(w_lag))
```

can I get the help to get the values of the previous month which I mentioned in approach2 column(expected results)

Comment: Can you edit and align the source data frame. Also, please give the expected output.

Comment: You've mentioned `lag` in your problem statement but you're code is using `lead`.

Comment: sorry its my bad... I am using lag

Comment: question is unclear about actual dataframe and the expected results. can you edit the question and make it more clear. why section is twice in your partitionBy clause?

Answer (score 1):

Check if below works for you.

First creating your Dataframe(Added Period 3 for validation of result, not caring about other columns)

```
l1 = [('49',52,179,'f',84,2019,1,63,0.616580311,5578.092,3439.341699),
('e4',52,179,'f',84,2019,1,31,0.248704663,5578.092,1387.297492),
('49',52,179,'f',84,2019,1,31,0.248704663,5578.092,1387.297492),
('a5',52,179,'f',84,2019,1,31,0.248704663,5578.092,1387.297492),
('49',52,179,'f',84,2019,2,63,0.080405405,18506.982,1488.061391),
('49',52,179,'f',84,2019,2,31,0.072297297,18506.982,1338.00478),
('e4',52,187,'f',84,2019,2,31,0.072297297,18506.982,1338.00478),
('e4',52,179,'f',84,2019,2,31,0.072297297,18506.982,1338.00478),
('e4',52,179,'f',84,2019,3,31,0.072297297,10006.982,1338.00478),
('e4',52,179,'f',84,2019,3,31,0.072297297,10006.982,1338.00478)]
```

Create Dataframe

```
dfl1 = spark.createDataFrame(l1).toDF('ut','cntr','src','Item','section','Year','Period','css','fct','ytd_1','ytd_1*fct')

dfl1.show()
+---+----+---+----+-------+----+------+---+-----------+---------+-----------+
| ut|cntr|src|Item|section|Year|Period|css|        fct|    ytd_1|  ytd_1*fct|
+---+----+---+----+-------+----+------+---+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 49|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     1| 63|0.616580311| 5578.092|3439.341699|
| e4|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     1| 31|0.248704663| 5578.092|1387.297492|
| 49|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     1| 31|0.248704663| 5578.092|1387.297492|
| a5|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     1| 31|0.248704663| 5578.092|1387.297492|
| 49|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     2| 63|0.080405405|18506.982|1488.061391|
| 49|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     2| 31|0.072297297|18506.982| 1338.00478|
| e4|  52|187|   f|     84|2019|     2| 31|0.072297297|18506.982| 1338.00478|
| e4|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     2| 31|0.072297297|18506.982| 1338.00478|
| e4|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     3| 31|0.072297297|10006.982| 1338.00478|
| e4|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     3| 31|0.072297297|10006.982| 1338.00478|
+---+----+---+----+-------+----+------+---+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Define Window. Here is the trick, we are giving range of -1 to 0 so it will always check one range above and then take the first value of previous range.

Range description from [official document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/WindowSpec.html#rangeBetween-long-long-)

> A range-based boundary is based on the actual value of the ORDER BY expression(s)

```
wl1 = Window.partitionBy(['Item','section','Year','css']).orderBy('Period').rangeBetween( -1, 0)
```

Now First value will be same for Period 1 so adding when function and marking as 0

```
dfl2 = dfl1.withColumn('Result', func.when(func.first(dfl1['ytd_1']).over(wl1) == dfl1['ytd_1'], func.lit(0)).otherwise(func.first(dfl1['ytd_1']).over(wl1)))

dfl2.orderBy('Period').show()

+---+----+---+----+-------+----+------+---+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
| ut|cntr|src|Item|section|Year|Period|css|        fct|    ytd_1|  ytd_1*fct|   Result|
+---+----+---+----+-------+----+------+---+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
| e4|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     1| 31|0.248704663| 5578.092|1387.297492|      0.0|
| a5|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     1| 31|0.248704663| 5578.092|1387.297492|      0.0|
| 49|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     1| 63|0.616580311| 5578.092|3439.341699|      0.0|
| 49|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     1| 31|0.248704663| 5578.092|1387.297492|      0.0|
| 49|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     2| 63|0.080405405|18506.982|1488.061391| 5578.092|
| e4|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     2| 31|0.072297297|18506.982| 1338.00478| 5578.092|
| 49|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     2| 31|0.072297297|18506.982| 1338.00478| 5578.092|
| e4|  52|187|   f|     84|2019|     2| 31|0.072297297|18506.982| 1338.00478| 5578.092|
| e4|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     3| 31|0.072297297|10006.982| 1338.00478|18506.982|
| e4|  52|179|   f|     84|2019|     3| 31|0.072297297|10006.982| 1338.00478|18506.982|
+---+----+---+----+-------+----+------+---+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
```